# NirCmd won't run on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, cmd.exe, compatibility, nircmd

I am using the NirCmd Command Line utility. It works fine on Windows 10, but I am trying to use it on Windows XP SP3. It says that it is not a Win32 compatible program. The website claims that it works on Windows XP - 10. I have turned off my antivirus and firewall and it still won't run. Is there anything I can do to get it to run on Win XP?

Comment: Got a 64-bit version of Windows XP? Why are you using XP anyway, it's pretty old, and long unsupported

Comment: I think its 32-bit... I am only using it because of its compact size. It is an MSI U123 Notebook.

Comment: Well, for now, is there _any_ way for me to run NirCmd on WinXP? The website says I should be able to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have accidentally downloaded the 64-bit version of NirCmd. This generally results in a *not a Win32 Application* error.

Use the 32-bit version available for download here:
http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.zip

P.S. Don't listen to people who try to scare you into upgrading. You are safe to stay with Windows XP if you have a decent firewall and avoid malicious sites while browsing the web.